# Study the series of $\int_0^{\frac{1}{n^a}}\sin{(\sqrt[3]{x})}\,dx$ with respect to $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I have to study the series $\sum a_n$ with $a_n=\int_0^{\frac{1}{n^a}}\sin{(\sqrt[3]{x})}\,dx$, with respect to $a>0$.

I have thought to use the asymptotic criterion for series.
In particular I can observe that:
$\sin{x}\sim x-\frac{x^3}{3!}$ and so: $\sin{(\sqrt[3]{x})}\sim \sqrt[3]{x}- \frac{x}{3!}$ for $x\to 0$.

Now this means that: $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{n^a}}\sqrt[3]{x}- \frac{x}{3!}\,dx=[\frac{x^{\frac{4}{3}}}{\frac{4}{3}}]\rvert_0^{\frac{1}{n^a}}-[\frac{x^{2}}{2\cdot 3!}]\rvert_0^{\frac{1}{n^a}}=\frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}n^{\frac{4}{3}a}}-\frac{1}{12n^{2a}}$$ Now since $\frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}n^{\frac{4}{3}a}}-\frac{1}{12n^{2a}}$ it self is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}n^{\frac{4}{3}a}}$ then I can say:
$$a_n\sim \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}n^{\frac{4}{3}a}}-\frac{1}{12n^{2a}}\sim \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}n^{\frac{4}{3}a}}$$
Now $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}n^{\frac{4}{3}a}}$ is convergent for $\frac{4}{3}a>1\iff a>\frac{3}{4}$ and so from asymptote criterion also the original series converges for this value of $a$.

I need a check of my attempt and in case there is something wrong can you tell me where and how can I correct this?

(I can't use the Lebesgue theore since it is not something that I know)

Comment: Oh yes surely! Thanks! Anyway my attempt is correct?

Comment: You can arrive at the conclusion faster by using the fact that $$
\frac{2}{\pi }w \leq  \sin w  \le w
$$ for all $0 \leq w\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Otherwise, your analysis is correct.

Comment: Heuristically, your analysis is correct but it is not a proof. There are many approximations in the reasoning. For example it is exactly the same to say $\sin(x)\sim x$ and $\sin(x)\sim x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$.

Comment: @Gribouillis so how can I correct my idea? So procedeeing with my idea but correcting the "inaccuracies"

Comment: If you want a complete proof of  the equivalent by your method, start by saying that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\eta>0$ such that $(1-\varepsilon)t \le \sin(t)\le t$ for $t\in [0, \eta]$. Then use these inequalities to bound the integral from above and from below.

Comment: @Gribouillis but what you are saying does not correct what you say is inexact, i.e $\frac{1}{4/3n^{4/3a}}-\frac{1}{12n^{2a}}\sim \frac{1}{4/3n^{4/3a}}$. If I use directly from the beginning that $\sin{\sqrt[3]{x}}\sim \sqrt[3]{3}$ it is better?

Comment: You are using an implicit rule that says that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous around $0$ and if $f(x)\sim g(x)$ when $x\to 0$ then $\int_0^{1/n^a}f(x) d x\sim \int_0^{1/n^a}g(x) d x$ when $n\to \infty$. It is true, but it deserves a proof. Then you can use that $\sin(x^{1/3})\sim x^{1/3}$ when $x\to 0$.

Comment: @Gribouillis what you are saying is to prove the asymptotic criterion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123676/discussion-between-pawel-and-gribouillis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more rigourous version of what you did. Using the Lagrange form of the remainder term in Taylor's formula, we have
$$
\left| {\sin w - w} \right| \le \frac{{w^3 }}{6}
$$
for all $w\geq 0$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\left| {a_n  - \frac{3}{{4n^{4a/3} }}} \right| &= \left| {\int_0^{1/n^a } {(\sin \sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{x})dx} } \right| \\ & \le \int_0^{1/n^a } {\left| {\sin \sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{x}} \right|dx}  \le \int_0^{1/n^a } {\frac{x}{6}dx}  = \frac{1}{{12n^{2a} }}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$
\left| {\frac{{a_n }}{{\frac{3}{{4n^{4a/3} }}}} - 1} \right| \le \frac{1}{{9n^{2a/3} }}
$$
showing that
$$
a_n  \sim \frac{3}{{4n^{4a/3} }}
$$
as $n\to +\infty$.

**Addendum.** By L'Hôpital's rule
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0} \frac{{\int_0^w {\sin \sqrt[3]{x}dx} }}{{\frac{3}{4}w^{4/3} }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0} \frac{{\sin \sqrt[3]{w}}}{{\sqrt[3]{w}}} = 1
$$
In particular, with $w=1/n^a$,
$$
a_n  \sim \frac{3}{{4n^{4a/3} }}
$$
as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: Two things: the last but one expression I think it is obtained mutliplying both hand sides of the inequality above by $\frac{4}{3n^{4/3a}}$...but by hand I have obtained $\frac{1}{9n^{10/3a}}$ and not $\frac{1}{9n^{2/3a}}$. Moreover why can I conclude the last?

Comment: You have to divide by $\frac{3}{{4n^{4a/3} }}$ and not multiply. Note that $2a-4a/3=2a/3$. You can then take the limit as $n\to \infty$ and see that $$
\left| {\frac{{a_n }}{{\frac{3}{{4n^{4a/3} }}}} - 1} \right|
$$ tends to $0$, i.e., $$\frac{{a_n }}{{\frac{3}{{4n^{4a/3} }}}}$$ tends to $1$.

Comment: Ok thanks now It is clear! Do you think that only stating that:since $\sin{\sqrt[3]{x}}\sim \sqrt[3]{x}$ and since $\int_0^{\frac{1}{n^a}}\sqrt[3]{x}=\frac{3}{4n^{a}/3}$ then $a_n\sim\frac{3}{4n^{a}/3}$, is not rigorous?

Comment: Well, why it is obvious that if two functions are asymptotic to each other at a given point then their integral functions are also asymptotic to each other at that point? Btw, I added a shorter proof that justifies this.

Comment: Ah ok...it is not obvious...and so the yours is the proof of this fact, right?

Comment: Another thing: the remainder in lagrange form is not $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x)^{n+1}$? So why $\frac{\omega^3}{6}$ and not $\frac{\omega^2}{2}$? I would write: $|\sin{x}-x|\leq \frac{c^2}{2}\leq \frac{x^2}{2}$ and this last since $c\in[0,x]$.

Comment: Look at the case $n=2$. Also you put the $c$ inside the derivative and not in place of $x$ (when you write "I would write").

Comment: Ah ok! The last thing I promise! The fact that you write $|a_n-\frac{3}{4n^{\frac{4a}{3}}}|$ and you estimate this it seems that in some sense you already know that $a_n\sim \frac{3}{4n^{\frac{4a}{3}}}$ and then you prove this...but if I had not know this why i should write $|a_n-\frac{3}{4n^{\frac{4a}{3}}}|$?

Comment: You can for example, guess it from your heuristics. This is how mathematics works.

Comment: Ok thanks! But the fact that two functions are asymptote in general does not mean that their integral are asymptote, right? I mean this is a particular case

Comment: Moreover and then stop ( :) ), it is a series of positive terms? I think yes since $\sin{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ for [0,c] with $c<1$ is positive and it is the case since $\frac{1}{n^a}<1$ for $a>0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123677/discussion-between-pawel-and-gary).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler proof of the equivalent: let $f(t) = \frac{\sin(t)}{t}$. It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) that $|f(t)|\le 1$ for all $t\in{\mathbb R}$ and that $f(0)=1$. The substitution $x = \frac{y}{n^a}$ in the integral gives
\begin{equation}
a_n = \left(\frac{1}{n^a}\right)^{4/3}\int_0^1 f\left(\left(\frac{y}{n^a}\right)^{1/3}\right) y^{1/3} d y
\end{equation}
By Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, the above integral converges to
$\int_0^1 y^{1/3} d y = \frac{3}{4}$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$, hence
\begin{equation}
a_n \sim \frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{n^a}\right)^{4/3}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks but in my knowledge there is no the Lebesgue theorem...there is another way to justify your conclusion?

Comment: Yes there is a way, you can prove that the function below the integral converges uniformly towards $y^{1/3}$ in $[0, 1]$. See the paragraph about the integral 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence . The convergence is also monotonous when $n$ is large enough and you could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem to prove directly that the convergence is uniform.