# Clarifications on $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ with $a_n=\int_0^{\frac{1}{n^a}}\sin{\sqrt[3]{x}}\, dx$ with $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I do this question as a sort of continuation of this previuous one ([Study the series of $\int_0^{\frac{1}{n^a}}\sin{(\sqrt[3]{x})}\,dx$ with respect to $a>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4122996/879543)), I mean I have other extra doubts related to this question that I have aked in comments but maybe it is the case to ask a question apart.

If I have $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ with $a_n=\int_0^{\frac{1}{n^a}}\sin{\sqrt[3]{x}}\, dx$ with $a>0$. I have $2$ questions:

$1)$ This is a positive terms series? I think yes since $\sin{(\sqrt[3]{x})}>0$ in $(0,n^{-a})\subseteq (0,1)$ and in $(0,1)$ I have $\sin{\sqrt[3]{x}}>0$

$2)$I have not understood why I use the Mclaurin polynomial of $\sin{\sqrt[3]{x}}$. I mean I have to consider that $x\to 0^+$ since when $n\to \infty$ I am in a neighbourhood of $0$?

$3)$When I have two asymptotic functions $f\sim g$ as $x\to 0$ then it is not necessarily true that $\int_0^{n^{-a}}f\sim \int_0^{n^{-a}}g$ as $n\to \infty$, right? Can I consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ as a counterexample?

Comment: @ClementC., why are not the functions $f,g$ of the original poster asymptotic? $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\frac1{\sqrt x}}{\frac1{\sqrt x}+\frac1{\sqrt[3]x}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{1+\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt[3]x}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{1+\sqrt[6]x}=1$$

Comment: @Angelo this is exactly what i have thought...but I thought it was wrong...

Comment: Because my brain was fried, and I misread $f$ and $g$ for $1/f$ and $1/g$. Deleted those comments...

Comment: Ok! But anyway the property holds in general?

Comment: @pawel I added an answer showing that, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, indeed.
2. Yes: if $\alpha\downarrow 0$, then since $0 \leq x\leq  \alpha$, $x$ goes to $0$ as well. (This is a little handwavy phrased like this, but that's the gist of it).
3. Let $\alpha \to 0^+$, and $f,g\geq 0$ such that $f\sim_0 g$. By definition, this means that there exists $\varepsilon\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = g(x)+\varepsilon(x)g(x)$ for all $x$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \varepsilon(x) = 0$. Now,
   $$
   \int_0^{\alpha} f(x)dx
   = \int_0^{\alpha} g(x)dx + \int_0^{\alpha} \varepsilon(x) g(x)dx
   $$
   Now, since
   $$
   \left|\int_0^{\alpha} \varepsilon(x) g(x)dx\right| \leq \sup_{x\in(0,\alpha)} |\varepsilon(x)| \cdot \int_0^{\alpha} g(x)dx
   $$
   and $\sup_{x\in(0,\alpha)} |\varepsilon(x)| \xrightarrow[\alpha\to 0]{} 0$, we do have
   $$
   \int_0^{\alpha} f
   = \int_0^{\alpha} g + o\!\left(\int_0^{\alpha} g \right)
   $$
   as $\alpha\to 0$, which means
   $$
   \int_0^{\alpha} f \operatorname*{\sim}_{\alpha \to 0}\int_0^{\alpha} g
   $$

Note that in the example you gave,
$$
\int_0^\alpha f = 2\alpha^{1/2}, \qquad \int_0^\alpha g = 2\alpha^{1/2} + \frac{3}{2}\alpha^{2/3} = 2\alpha^{1/2} + o(\alpha^{1/2})
$$
so there is no contradiction.

Comment: Ok very thanks! The last question: if I have the integral from 1 to $x$ the situation changes? For instance $\lim_{x\to 0}\int_1^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\neq \lim \lim_{x\to 0}\int_1^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$

Comment: @pawel you can't have the same $x$ as dummy variable for the integral (the thing you integrate against), and bound of the integral. That's not mathematically valid: did you mean something else?

Comment: Oh yes sorry it is a typo. I mean something like $\int_1^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt$

Comment: Moreover in $2)$ do you mean $0\leq x\leq \alpha$, right?

Comment: @pawel yes, good catch - that was a typo. Regarding your question: indeed, in that case you're no longer in a neighbourhood of 0, so the conclusion doesn't hold (and the proof doesn't go through, can you see where it'd fail?). You would need extra/different assumptions, off the top of my head something like divergence of the integrals at 0.

Comment: Ok thanks! Nope I can't understand where fails the proof in this case! Can you tell me where please?

Comment: @pawel the supremum of $\varepsilon(x)$ for x in $[\alpha,1]$ may not tend to 0.